# Jquery slide animation for validation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to slidedown a div on focus of input field for validation.
I wanted to achieve animation something like https://mailchimp.com/signup/

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6A9Qa/

```
$('#name').on('focus',function() {
   $(this).next().show().animate({height: '25px'}, {duration: 250});

});

$('#name').on('blur',function() {
    $(this).next().hide().animate({height: '0'}, {duration: 250}); 
});
```

I'm not able to get animation in proper way like mail chimp.

Comment: instead of animating the height, why dont you use slideDown/slideUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/6A9Qa/9/

```
(function() {
  $('#name').on('focus',function() {
    $(this).next().show().animate({height: '25px'},250);
  });
  $('#name').on('blur',function() {
     $(this).next().animate({height: '0'}, 250, function(){
        $('.validate').hide();
     });
  });
})();
```

and there is one more requirement to add a `height:0;` css property to the `.validate` css Class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use slidedown and up

```
$('#name').on('focus',function() {
   $(this).next().slideDown(2000);
});

$('#name').on('blur',function() {
   $(this).next().slideUp(2000);
});
```

then just edit on your css the element's height.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use.. [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function

> SLIDEUP:Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.
>   SLIDEDOWN:  Display the matched elements with a sliding motion.

```
$('#name').on('focus',function() {
 $(this).next().slideDown('slow');

});

$('#name').on('blur',function() {
 $(this).next().slideUp('slow');

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6A9Qa/5/)

Answer (score 0):

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6A9Qa/8/):

```
(function () {

  $('#name').on('focus', function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });

  $('#name').on('blur', function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
 });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try my demo here http://jsfiddle.net/6A9Qa/7/

```
(function() {

  $('#name').on('focus',function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.generic').slideDown(250);
  });

   $('#name').on('change',function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.generic').slideUp(250);
     if($('#name').val() !== ''){
        $(this).nextAll('.error').slideDown(250);
     }
     else {
        $(this).nextAll('.error').slideUp(250);
     }
  });

})();
```